# Save as popup for itext generated PDF

Tags: java, servlets, itext

I have a doubt regarding save as Popup for iText generated PDF. From some of the previous similar question i came to know that, by putting below codes one popup will open for saving file.

```
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");Document my_pdf_report = new Document();
```

But for me its not working.I am calling the java class from Ajax function. Is that the reason for not working ?